# Limitation to modify the tags of a question

Tags: feature-request, tags

Regarding: question editing

It would be better to restrict the modification of a tag question. At least by allowing only to modify one at time and also require to provide a reason of more than 50 characters

Comment: Why should this be done  ?

Comment: becaise it is anoying when someone delete a tag in your question. And you are pretty sure the tag is consistemt with the field of knowledge of the question

Comment: What is the problem exactly and why is it a bug? Are you asking to limit editing of tags to only one at a time? If so, why is it a problem that we add / replace 5 tags at once for better ones?  Or that suggestededit comment should have a less restrictive minimal length?

Comment: @rene from the original text I would guess the first. (At most one change)

Comment: I think it can be considered a "light customer side security bug" because it is related to prevent someone from modify your own question in a "key" part of it (the keywords)

Comment: @ManuelMilla so you want to limit the amount of tags that can be changed in one edit to one?

Comment: @Johan Yes, because, that is the best way to relate the modofication with the reason provided

Comment: @Manuel but it would be less than 50 characters.

Comment: @ManuelMilla: Stack Exchange greatly values editing, and, by design, allows users to edit others' posts in order to improve them in any way consistent with the original author's basic intent. So allowing, say, tags to be changed is not a security bug. It's a central part of site design. (There is no automatic way to tell if a given edit respects the original author's intent, since the entire point is to allow full human creativity and sound judgement; if you could tell automatically, you could also make the edits automatically.)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the only thing that will happen as a result of preventing users from modifying more than one tag at a time is a bunch of unnecessary revisions. If someone wants to modify the tags, they aren't gonna stop just because they have to do one tag edit per revision.

In response to requiring a 50 character description, this just isn't going to help anything. It's generally pretty obvious that the editor is just adding relevant tags or removing irrelevant ones. In the cases where a description is required, very few to none of them will require 50 characters, and there's no reason to force people to make them a lot longer than necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Why should this be done?

What if someone uses totally wrong tags for a question? -> you have to change all tags

What if the reason for a change is obvious? -> you don’t need an edit reason

Also all edits are open to review as the post is bumped to the front page. Abuse is therefore quite unlikely and dealt with quickly.

If you disagree with a change, roll back the edit or edit it back.

There is really no reason to do this.

Comment: I am asking for "Limitations..." that means that it allow the one who modify the tag, to provide a reason of no less than 50 chatacters

Comment: @ManuelMilla but what if the reason is “wrong tags”?

Answer (score 4):

There's already a feature that exists to tell you when a tag should and shouldn't be used: tag excerpts. You can see this by hovering over a tag, and many tags also have extended guidelines in the full wiki. For example, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) is the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) wiki.

If the editor doesn't feel like this is enough explanation, they can leave a comment (either a proper comment or as the edit summary). If someone edits your question (or you have 50 rep on the site and it's someone else's question), you can use [@username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/323179) to ping the editor about their edit.

What you're suggesting would end up needlessly wasting editors a lot of time, time that could be better spent on doing more important things: answering or asking questions, making more edits, IRL things, etc. This restriction will also prevent some people from making edits at all. There is always going to be more content that needs attention than editors, so it's very important that editing be as easy as possible.